# MYSQL Inner Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am using the MYSQL, in that i try the following select query's

```
SELECT col_A,Col_B FROM table_A WHERE Col_C in (1,2)
```

this query display is 2 record, but i tried the following query i got only one record

```
SELECT col_A,Col_B FROM table_A WHERE Col_C in (
SELECT col_A FROM table_B WHERE Col_B)
```

the output of the "SELECT col_A FROM table_B WHERE Col_B" is 1,2

Comment: incomplete `where` condition in inner query

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your mysql query. Please check again the result of  `SELECT col_A FROM table_B WHERE Col_B` query.

If You can display your table content or in `www.sqlfiddle.com` site  please make your tables with some content so we can check what is problem come here.

thank you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for response, still i got the same problem, i check the "SELECT col_A FROM table_B WHERE Col_B" i got the value in "1,2"

Comment: Hi, can you please add your tables in `www.sqlfiddle.com` with data so i can check there..If this possible. And are you running query direct in mysql or by any programing language. thanks